# Dynamic LinearLayout with same height as width

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to create a dynamic `LinearLayout` with the same height as width. With XML I can achieve this by setting the the height as *0px* i.e. `android:layout_height="0dp"`. But I'm not able to achieve the same thing while creating the layout from Java code.

```html
LinearLayout parentLayout = layoutInflater.inflate();

LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.height = 0;

parentLayout.addView(childLayout, layoutParams);
```

I want the childLayout to be of the same height as width but the height appears to be set to `WRAP_CONTENT` instead, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
layoutParams.weight = layoutParams.height
```